# Restart/Release rfcomm for bluetooth communication

Tags: python, ubuntu, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect raspberry pi to my galaxy note to use it for serial communication. I have somewhat succeeded at that.

First I paired it and trusted through `bluetoothctl`. Then I run `sudo rfcomm watch hci0` and opened with `cat /dev/rfcomm`. I was able to connect to raspberry pi using bluetooth terminal (only this app, every other one failed) and strings sent from galaxy would be shown in the `cat` window.

I have somehow messed up later and now running `sudo rfcomm watch hci0` gives me `Can't bind RFCOMM socket: Address already in use`. I can't release it with `sudo rfcomm release hci0` or `sudo rfcomm release 0` as it then gives me Can't release device: No such device. Likewise `cat /dev/rfcomm0` too now gives me No such file or directory.

I killed the process listed with `sudo lsof | grep /dev/rfcomm0`, this had no effect on my ability to use RFCOMM. Reloading with `systemctl daemon-reload` and restarting with `service bluetooth restart` too has had no effect.

I can still scan for other bluetooth devices, and I can connect to raspberry pi with bluetooth terminal, but it seems `rfcomm` is gone. I am aware that rebooting can solve this, though I would like to do that programatically if possible without having to resort to power-cycling.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pair device with raspberry pi..

`bluetoothctl`

`scan on`

`pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

`trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

`agent-on`

**Configure Bluetooth Device**

`hciconfig`

to create serial on pi, /dev/rfcomm

`sudo rfcomm watch hci0`

`sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan`

`sudo sdptool add sp`

`sudo rfcomm watch hci0`